# Another preinstalled windows 8(sony vaio), I have no idea what to do next.

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-8, vaio, sony

I recently bought a laptop with preinstalled windows 8. Did a clean install via the installation manager at first and got it to work. Then there was an issue when I tried the ati proprietary drivers that I was unable to resolve so I made a clean install again. How ever this time it won't work and I get the "no operating system found" on boot. What can possibly have changed since the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I managed to solve it by switching to legacy mode in Bios, this way I don't seem to have to use an efi partition or anything and the installation works just as usual. You have to switch before the install though, probably got something to do with grub.